# how to check if a method can be handler of an event through C# reflection?

Tags: c#, events, reflection, methods, delegates

I create an event based system, where a class will provides bunch of events, and another class with its member method can attach to the first class as its event handler, and... i just want to do something like this

```
if(isMethodCompatibleToEvent(...))
{
    connectMethodToEvent(...)
}
```

through reflection, this is how the connecting is done :

```
void connectMethodToEvent(object methodTarget, MethodInfo mi,
    object eventTarget, EventInfo ei)
{
    Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, methodTarget, mi);
    ei.AddEventHandler(eventTarget, handler);
}
```

if the method is not compatible to an event, it will throw an exception, to fix this i want to create some checking before i create the method delegate, but how?

```
bool isMethodCompatibleToEvent(object methodTarget, MethodInfo mi,
    object eventTarget, EventInfo ei)
{
    // HOW ?
}
```

Comment: For the lazy ones, the duplicate linked by @SLaks has an accepted answer which uses [this overload of `Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdzt99sk.aspx) where you can specify with a Boolean `throwOnBindFailure` if you want exception or not.

Comment: If your exception comes from the line where `handler` is assigned, change your overload of `CreateDelegate` to include `throwOnBindFailure` to be false. Then check if `handler` becomes `null` before proceeding. If your exception comes from the second line, the `AddEventHandler` call, there's something strange. Note that the type of `handler` should match the type of the event exactly (don't try to use contravariance in generics with events).

Answer (score 2):

- The number of formal parameters must be the same.
- The "refness" of the formal parameters must be the same. (Technically a method with an `out` parameter may be used for an event with a `ref` parameter and vice versa but I don't recommend it.)
- Each formal parameter type must be compatible. For value types they must match exactly. For formal parameters of reference type, contravariance is permitted. That is, if you have an event handler that is going to pass a Giraffe to the delegate, the delegate is permitted to take Animal.
- The "voidness" of the return type must be the same; `void` only matches `void`.
- For non-void return types, value types must match exactly. For event handlers that return reference types, covariance is permitted. That is, if the event handler says that it returns Animal and the delegate returns Giraffe, that's fine.

These are not all the rules but they are enough to deal with the vast majority of common cases.

Comment: `(Technically a method with an out parameter may be used for an event with a ref parameter and vice versa but I don't recommend it.)` Does that mean you can escape the definite-assignment requirements without reflection?

Comment: Trying it out, it looks like the compile doesn't allow it as an implicit conversion.

Comment: @SLaks: since "out" is from the CLR's perspective nothing more than "ref" with an attribute on it, there are a number of sneaky ways to unify methods with "out" parameters with methods with "ref" parameters. I don't recall what they are at this moment, but basically there are some ways to do end-runs around the compiler. The definite assignment rules around "out" are merely conventions of the C# language; they are in no way enforced by the runtime.

Comment: Yes; I should have realized that.  I guess `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is "reflective" enough to violate C#'s _language_ rules (since the CLR is weaker).  What other ways exist? Overrides? Other languages?

Comment: @SLaks: Overrides: yes, I seem to recall that there was some way to mess with the refness/outness via overrides but I do not recall the details. Other languages, absolutely; you can do whatever you want in IL.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compare the signature of the method and delegate (definition the event's type): if they match then the method can be combined to the event.

An exact match of parameter and return types is clearly easiest, but also consider that implicit conversions can also be applied (depending on your requirements using `Type.IsAssignableFrom` might be sufficient).

Checking the C# Language specification for the rules about type compatibility for methods and events would be a first step.